# Calculate dead time in synchronous buck converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

How much dead time is required for the switches in synchronous buck converter at a switching frequency let's say 1 kHz. Is there any thumb rule for choosing dead time with respect to the switching frequency?

Comment: It depends on the MOSFETs chosen.

Comment: You choose one, then you trace with a scope if it's good.

Comment: Does this help? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/246571/how-to-calculate-the-dead-time-to-incorporate-in-the-complementay-pwm-input-to-a

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link @ocrdu. Understood.